# ESP8266 - How to get the current SSID?

Tags: esp8266, at-command

I'm trying to write a state machine on my processor. I'm using the ESP module to communicate over Wi-Fi. When the module is powered up it connects to an AP which was already specified in its flash memory. I would like to check whether if the connecte AP is the one that my system requires or not. Is there an AT command to get the currently connected SSID name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AT+<x>?` is an inquiry

`AT+<x>=<...>` is a set command

as such:
[`AT+ CWJAP?`](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/CWJAP)
Is the inquiry about the SSID

Comment: If answer is a good answer and/or the accepted one then please [vote the answer up and/or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This rewards both you and me and makes it clear to others what the best/correct answer is.

Comment: More specific, AT commands have three forms variations, 1) *Action*, e.g. `AT+CMD` or `AT+CMD=...`, 2) *Read*, e.g. `AT+CMD?` and 3) *Test*, e.g. `AT+CMD=?`, see chapter 5 in [V.250](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). Some AT commands only supports one or two of those forms.

Comment: @hlovdal feel free to add this to the answer by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56681613/edit)